# Modifying Businessx code to dynamically create clickable icons

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working with a WordPress theme called BusinessX, and they have a plugin called Businessx-extensions which allows them to have control over functions like the one in question today - the features section. This is esentially just a grid of icons. However, I want said icons to be clickable. So I found the place where that happens...

```
// Figure
if( ! function_exists( 'bx_ext_item__features_figure' ) ) {
    function bx_ext_item__features_figure( $widget_options ) {
        $show  = $widget_options['show_figure'];
        $type  = $widget_options['figure_type'];
        $icon  = $widget_options['figure_icon'];
        $image = $widget_options['figure_image'];
        $title = $widget_options['title'];
        $format = $output = '';

        switch ( $type ) {
            case 'ft-icon':
                $format = ( $icon != '' ) ? '<figure class="sec-feature-figure"><a href="/"'.$burl.'>%s</a></figure>' : '';
                $output = ( $format != '' ) ? sprintf( $format, businessx_icon( $icon, FALSE, FALSE ) ) : '';
                break;
            case 'ft-image':
                $format = ( $image != '' ) ? '<figure class="sec-feature-figure-img"><img src="%s" alt="image" /></figure>' : '';
                $output = ( $format != '' ) ? sprintf( $format, esc_url( $image ) ) : '';
                break;
        }

        $output = apply_filters( 'bx_ext_item___features_figure', $output, $widget_options );

        if( $show ) {
            echo $output;
        }
    }
}
```

So I edited the line that starts with $format =  ( $icon !=... and added in an anchor and a variable I declared at the top of my class called **burl**.

Burl is supposed to be set by another function built in that is part of the customizer. Here is another function from the same file.

```
// Button
    if( ! function_exists( 'bx_ext_item__features_contents_button' ) ) {
        function bx_ext_item__features_contents_button( $widget_options ) {
            $anchor = $widget_options['btn_anchor'];
            $url    = $widget_options['btn_url'];
            $burl = $url;
            $burl = 'beef';
            $target = $widget_options['btn_target'];
            $format = '<a href="%1$s" target="%2$s" class="ac-btn-alt fw-bolder">%3$s</a>';

            $output = sprintf( $format, esc_url( $url ), esc_attr( $target ), esc_html( $anchor ) );
            $output = apply_filters( 'bx_ext_item___features_contents_button', $output, $format, $widget_options );

            if( $anchor == '' ) return;

            echo $output;
        }
    }
```

But, for the life of me, I cannot seem to get this to return either beef OR the specified URL. Ok. Then I found the file for add_actions...

```
    /**
 * Features items
 */
add_action( 'bx_ext_item__features', 'bx_ext_item__features_figure',   10, 1 );
add_action( 'bx_ext_item__features', 'bx_ext_item__features_contents', 20, 1 );

add_action( 'bx_ext_item__features_contents', 'bx_ext_item__features_contents_start',    10, 1 );
add_action( 'bx_ext_item__features_contents', 'bx_ext_item__features_contents_title',    20, 1 );
add_action( 'bx_ext_item__features_contents', 'bx_ext_item__features_contents_excerpt',  30, 1 );
add_action( 'bx_ext_item__features_contents', 'bx_ext_item__features_contents_button',   40, 1 );
add_action( 'bx_ext_item__features_contents', 'bx_ext_item__features_contents_end',     999, 1 );
```

Aaaand I am stuck. No matter how I rearrange or reprioritize these, I never see the anchor links return beef or the URL specified. I'm at a loss of what else I should try.

Any thoughts? Long one, sorry. Thank you.

Comment: Problem is the order of method execution I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url is set through the customizer when you add a new feature, so it's there all along, it doesn't depend on any external action. Use:

```
'<figure class="sec-feature-figure"><a href="'.$widget_options['btn_url'].'">%s</a></figure>'
```

However, if you modify the plugin directly, your changes will be overwritten when you update it. The proper way to do it is overriding the action in your child theme `functions.php` (they [provide one](http://www.acosmin.com/download/61/)).

```
function bx_ext_custom_item__features_figure($widget_options) {
// Copy the function body with your modifications here
}

// Remove the original function creating the figure
remove_action('bx_ext_item__features', 'bx_ext_item__features_figure');
// Call yours instead
add_action('bx_ext_item__features', 'bx_ext_custom_item__features_figure', 10, 1);
```